# How to convert an interval to milliseconds in duckdb?

Tags: duckdb

I'm looking for a way to perform calculations on intervals in duckdb, for instance sums or percentages:

```
select sum(duration) from downtimes;
# => Error: Binder Error: No function matches the given name and argument types 'sum(INTERVAL)'. You might need to add explicit type casts.
#        Candidate functions:
#        sum(DECIMAL) -> DECIMAL
```

One way could be to cast my interval to an integer duration (e.g. in milliseconds), work on integers and convert back.

But while I easily found a `to_milliseconds(integer) => interval`, I can't seem to find the reverse function.

I guess I could go with something like:

```
millisecond(duration) + second(duration) * 1000 + minute(duration) * 1000 * 60 + ... + year(duration) * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365
```

but I'm thinking there has to be something simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the simplest I could find if you need millisecond precision:

```
epoch(interval) * 1000 + milliseconds(interval)
```

If seconds are good enough, then `epoch(interval)` will do the job.

For a sum, you'll need to add an explicit cast to `bigint` to convert the result back to interval:

```
SELECT TO_MILLISECONDS(
  CAST(
    SUM(EPOCH(duration) * 1000 + MILLISECONDS(duration))
    AS BIGINT)
  )
)
FROM downtimes;
```

Answer (score 1):

starting with duckdb v0.9.0 epoch now returns the seconds as a double and a new function, epoch_ms, is available to get the milliseconds as an integer.

```
select epoch_ms(interval 1 day);
```

which will return the milliseconds as an integer.
or

```
select epoch(interval 1 day);
```

which will return seconds as a double.

for versions earlier than 0.9.0

```
select (date_part('epoch', interval 2 seconds) - date_part('sec', interval 2 seconds)) * 1000 + date_part('ms', interval 2 seconds);
```

note that `date_part('ms', xxx)` is the sub-minute milliseconds not sub-second.

but that will not work with v0.9.0 because epoch returns a double, so to work with v0.9.0 and earlier versions, something like:

```
select (trunc(date_part('epoch', interval 2 seconds))::bigint - date_part('sec', interval 2 seconds)) * 1000 + date_part('ms', interval 2 seconds);
```